How to set site access default to onClick
I am building a cromeExtention & I want to set site access default to onClick , right now when ever I install extention it is by default selected to on all sites
is there any setting in menifist file for this ?
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "site",
  "description": "site extention",
  "background": { "service_worker": "background.bundle.js" },
  "action": {
    "default_icon": "icon-34.png"
  },
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon-34.png",
    "16": "icon-34.png"
  },
  "host_permissions": [
    "https://*.linkedin.com/*",
    "https://resdex.naukri.com/*",
    "https://www.naukrigulf.com/*"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": ["contentScript.bundle.js"],
      "css": ["content.styles.css"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }
  ],
  "devtools_page": "devtools.html",
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": [
        "content.styles.css",
        "icon-128.png",
        "icon-34.png",
        "logo.svg",
        "logoFull.svg",
        "modS.svg",
        "linkD.svg",
        "NaukriD.png"
      ],
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "storage", "scripting", "contextMenus"]
}



Use activeTab permission, but also remove content_scripts and host_permissions (if you need any of these, show the code and explain why - there's a way to do it on demand).

I already have activeTab permission,

My comment mentions other things, you need to deal with those too.

@woxxom I have added my manifest file and imgae what I am looking for , can you help me understand

You'll have to remove content_scripts and host_permissions and then use chrome.scripting.executeScript inside chrome.action.onClicked to inject your content scripts.

@woxxom tried this also .. no luck

You mean the setting is not shown? It doesn't matter, because the extension actually works on click now, assuming you applied the changes correctly.
